# How to open a new TWebBrowser on a script?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I have a website (I cannot change) having this script:

```html
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="if (this.checked) openNew()">

function openNew() 
    { 
    window.open("/help?aide=77", "aproposde", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=300, height=250, left=500, top=300"); 
    }
```

I try to use `TWebBrowser`, but on new window event, always opens an empty browser:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.wwwNewWindow2(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch;
  var Cancel: WordBool);
var NF: TForm1;
begin
  NF := TForm1.Create(Application);
  NF.Visible := True;
  NF.www.RegisterAsBrowser;
  ppDisp := NF.www.DefaultInterface;
end;
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: sorry: just paste that from another answer... and NF is the ONLY variable used here. So that's ok for 5 lines codes snippet !

Comment: Sure. It's fine. Until next month, when that five line code snippet has grown into a 20 or 30 line procedure, and then six months later when someone other than you has to go in and try to read it and fix something. There's no excuse for sloppy code, even in five line code snippets. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NewWindow3 event as following

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NewWindow3(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch;
   var Cancel: WordBool; dwFlags: Cardinal; const bstrUrlContext, bstrUrl: WideString);
var NF: TForm1;
begin
  NF := TForm1.Create(Application);
  NF.Visible := True;       
  Cancel := True;
  NF.www.Navigate(bstrUrl);
end;
```